# the most recent Geobased ARSDKs for Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

im trying to build a geobased AR application for Android and i want a free SDK, 
all the SDKs i found are about 4 years old since the eclipse era (ex: [droidAr](https://github.com/bitstars/droidar) and [BeyondAR](http://www.beyondar.com/)
Why aren't there updating for different SDKs and what arethe most recent i could use

Answer (score 1):

Most of those projects are old and not further maintained. Why? You should ask the developers in charge...

Regarding others you can use - I would check [Mixare](http://www.mixare.org/), which is also open source. Also, have a look in this SDK review, seek those marked with GPS: [Augmented Reality SDK Comparison](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks).